# Disabling Intellisense with VS 2022 editing non-source files

Tags: visual-studio

I'm editing some .INI files with detailed comments in VS 2022 (v. 17.3.6), and it keeps bugging me with auto completion, word guessing, and ending quotes where unneeded...
Is there a simple way to stop it from *helping* me?

As I go back and forth to C# files is helpful, but **not** with plain text!

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> IntelliCode
`Change the settings from there.`